# how to know if a returned value is a future or not

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am trying to know if a returned variable from a callback, that is defined to return dynamic, is a future or not. The Goal is to know whether to `await` it or not.

here is a sample code of what I want to know :

```dart
dynamic returnedValue = callbackPassedFromArguments();
//the next line is what I want to know

if(isFuture(returnedValue))
{
 dynamic realReturnedValue = await returnedValue;
}
....
```

is there a function that can replace the `isFuture` psudoFunction I mentioned ?

Comment: The answer was Future.value which completely ignores weather the argument it gets is a value or a future. that is exactly what I needed.

Comment: `Future.value` is a *constructor* for a `Future`.  It won't tell you whether an existing `Object` is a `Future`.

Comment: To answer your original question: you could just use `returnedValue is Future`.  Or just `await returnedValue` unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether something is a future, just do a type check `returnedValue is Future`.

In this case I'd do:

```dart
if (returnedValue is Future) {
 returnedValue = await returnedValue;
}
```

You *can* also just do:

```dart
 returnedValue = await returnedValue;
```

The result is the same, but the latter code will introduce an asynchronous delay because it actually wraps the `returnedValue` into a future if it is not a future, then awaits that future.